C# LINQ OrderBy with an explicit culture returns different results on different .NET versions
I have a list of English and Korean words that I am trying to order so that the Korean words are ordered first, with the English words being ordered last.
This SO post is my exact issue: C# linq order by depending on Language
However, I couldn't get this to work in my .NET 4.7.2 MVC application. I have used the exact same code from this post:
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "NIKE", "한글", "adidas", "한글Korean" };

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR");
StringComparer comp = StringComparer.Create(ci, true);

var ordered = stringArray.OrderBy(s => s, comp);
var output = string.Join(", ", ordered.ToArray());

In my 4.7.2 application, this outputs "adidas, NIKE, 한글, 한글Korean" which is not what I want.
I was confused as to why this wasn't working, so I tried a .NET 8 console application and with the exact same code snippet, the output was "한글, 한글Korean, adidas, NIKE" which is exactly what I want.
I found this document that mentions globalization changes as of .NET 5 which I suspect is the cause of this, though I'm not entirely sure what the solution is to work around this without having to write something custom: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu
Is there a solution for this I can use in 4.7.2 to order the English words last without having to write something custom?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79084844/date-format-culture-differences-with-net-4-8-and-net-8/79085322#79085322 You can't fix it for .NET 4.x, all you can do is to make .NET 5+ work like .NET 4.x, which isn't what you want.

So your requirement is that of the string contains Hangul syllables it should come first?

You can't get this to work on .NET Framework .NET 5+ is .NET Core 5, a completely different, cross-platform runtime and SDK, not a newer version of .NET Framework 4.8. Microsoft removed the Core part with the release of .NET 5 for marketing purposes - people that feared compatibility issues were more likely to migrate if the name didn't sound like a different platform. In .NET Framework, collation and ordering are provided by Windows. In .NET Core, they're provided by ICU. In .NET Framework you'd have to create a custom Culture or comparer using the rules you want.

Try this,
public static class Sorter
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> OrderKoreanFirst(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        // orders by the string starts with Korean characters 
        return strings.OrderBy(s => IsKorean(s[0]) ? 0 : 1)
                        .ThenBy(s => s, StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko-KR"), true));
    }

    
    private static bool IsKorean(char c)
    {
        // Unicode ranges for Korean characters
        return (c >= '\u1100' && c <= '\u11FF') || (c >= '\u3130' && c <= '\u318F')
    }
}

string[] stringArray = new string[] { "NIKE", "한글", "adidas", "한글Korean" };
var ordered = Sorter.OrderKoreanFirst(stringArray);
var output = string.Join(", ", ordered); // Output: "한글, 한글Korean, adidas, NIKE"

The OrderKoreanFirst method accepts an IEnumerable<string> as
input and returns an ordered collection with Korean
character-starting strings first.

It first checks if each string starts with a Korean character using
the helper method IsKorean.
If a string starts with a Korean character, it assigns it a sort key
of 0; otherwise, it assigns 1. This ensures that Korean strings are
prioritized in sorting.
After separating Korean and non-Korean strings, it sorts each subset
alphabetically using a culture-aware StringComparer with ko-KR (Korean) cultural sorting rules.

The IsKorean method checks if a character (char c) falls within one of the Unicode ranges associated with Korean characters:
\u1100 to \u11FF: Hangul Jamo
\u3130 to \u318F: Hangul Compatibility Jamo

If the character falls within these ranges, it returns true, indicating it’s a Korean character.
After calling OrderKoreanFirst, it joins the sorted results into a single string (output) with the expected order
